# How to format URL for an image file in a website directory named with URL escape characters

Tags: url, web, escaping

I have a very unique problem (I think).

Some human (I think), named a website directory "hello%20world". I want to get at the images in that directory by calling:

http://website/images/hello%20world/image.jpg

But, the browser or Curl or Fiddler or Powershell's Invoke-RestMethod translates that to:

http://website/images/hello world/image.jpg

...which is not found.

Other than changing the directory name, what other options do I have to escape the escape characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url encode your entire path?

`images%2Fhello%2520world%2Fimage.jpg`

or some variation on that theme ?

Comment: That works until you have an actual space. Then you get a '+' in the name. Boom!

Comment: hmm... I'd have expected that `+` to be interpreted by browsers correctly

Comment: can you just scan for the handful of known bad characters, and replace() them with their urlencoded values... instead of the entire path string

Comment: I'll give you this answer though. You obviously worked very hard on the answer. :P